# Postfix trying to deliver remote aliases locally

Tags: postfix

I'm taking over admin of a postfix installation so please consider me a postfix begginner. It's using ViMbadmin for configuration, and the problem described below only recently appeared and was definitely not happening approx 1 week ago. There are some cron scripts that do updates but no specific known changes that would have caused this.

Main problem is e.g.:

```
Sep  3 14:49:00 mail postfix/pipe[11415]: CC8FA95A: to=<SOMEBODY@gmail.com>, orig_to=<support@MYDOMAIN.org>, relay=spamassassin, delay=2.2, delays=0.48/0.01/0/1.7, dsn=4.1.1, status=SOFTBOUNCE (user unknown)
```

I'm interpreting this error as postfix trying to route mail to gmail to a local user called SOMEBODY@gmail.com and complaining it doesn't exist.

Possibly relevant parts of configuration from main.cf:

```
# mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
```

and

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_domains_maps.cf
```

As far as I can tell the setup to query the MySQL table for the locally managed domains is correct and contains MYDOMAIN

Thanks for any help. Additionally have just discovered that mysql *may* have been down but is now definitely up and postfix restarted, however problem persists.

Edit more complete log and config info here: http://termbin.com/nabi

Comment: Please show the rest of the log entries for the same message ID.

Comment: @MichaelHampton added link to paste

Comment: Are those log entries complete?

Comment: @MichaelHampton 'complete' how? it's the whole session i see in mail.info (which seems to have more than mail.log), when an email is sent to a postfix alias.

Comment: I've narrowed the issue down a bit: it's only to do with postfix aliases, and it's somehow related to spamassassin. If a single mail is sent out through a mailbox it works fine. If spamassassin content filter is disabled, then everything works fine.